# Add new field when showing a comment

Tags: comments

As you know comments are displayed like this:

[image]

So it shows the subject, and then says: Comment and shows the comment body.

So I have a new field in comment table called "paragraph_id", so before the comment subject, I want to say: 
          Paragraph Number: 
  and then display the value in paragraph_id value.

How can I do it? Which hook should I use?

Comment: Hacking new fields into existing core tables is a bad idea - you should really use the field system that Drupal provides. Then you can do all this through the UI

Comment: @clive, So what is that field system that Drupal provides? I have  to mention that I have used hook_form_comment_form_alter, hook_form_comment_form_validate, hook_form_comment_form_submit hooks for adding my new field.